# Apache conf files getting an AH00526: Syntax error

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I restarted my WAMP server and I encountered an error

> There is a syntax error in Apache conf files.
> AH00526: Syntax error on line 10 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.51/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
> Unknown Authz provider: access

My httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like this:

```
    # Virtual Hosts
 #
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require access denied    
  </Directory>
```

What should I put instead of "Require access denied"?

Comment: Not sure what `Require access denied` is supposed to achieve? Did you mean either `Require all denied`, perhaps? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

Comment: Ahh I see I got it mixed up. Thank you so much for the link!